# The __main__ in <function __main__.add_numbers(x, y)>

Tags: python, ipython

Suppose such a function:

```
 In [56]: def add_numbers(x, y): return x + y
```

When I use it without parentheses

```
In [57]: add_numbers
Out[57]: <function __main__.add_numbers(x, y)>
```

What's `__main__` for here?
It does not lie in `add_numbers`s standard or meta attributes:

```
In [59]: "__main__" in dir(add_numbers)
Out[59]: False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing an IPython feature.  It uses a pretty-printer which prepends the module name to the function's [qualified name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/).  If you disable the pretty-printer, you will get the [usual function repr](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b92c526ed5da474694f89e29d82565f2a654c29b/Objects/funcobject.c#L554-L559):

```
>>> def add_numbers(x, y): return x + y
... 
>>> add_numbers
<function __main__.add_numbers(x, y)>
>>> %pprint
Pretty printing has been turned OFF
>>> add_numbers
<function add_numbers at 0x107921598>
```

The function's module is `__main__` because you've defined it interactively.  If you had imported it from some other module, you would see the module name there instead.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html):

> `'__main__'` is the name of the scope in which top-level code
>   executes. A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read
>   from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.

Since you are running Python from standard input, the module name is set to `'__name__'`, and all the variables and functions defined are in the scope of this module.

Comment: I wrote this code but my code prints something else:
`def main():<br>
 def add_numbers(x, y): return x + y
 print(add_numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()`
I got this:  
`<function main.<locals>.add_numbers at 0x7f21d39f40d0>`